# PHP "file_exists" on Windows 7 (UserName)

Tags: php, windows, file-exists

i'm doing this check via PHP... 
i'd like to know if a program is installed.

```
if (file_exists("C:\\Users\\**USERNAME**\\AppData\\Roaming\\xXXx\\xXXx\\xXXx.exe"))
```

how do i get (retrieve automatically) the `USERNAME?`

let me say i'd like to do something corresponding to this (used in a batch file)......

```
if exist %SystemDrive%\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Roaming\xXXx\xXXx\xXXx.exe
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you've set IIS to authenticate users one or more of these should contain the username:

```
$_SERVER['LOGON_USER']
$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_LOGON_USER']
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_AUTH_USER']
```

Comment: thanks, but something like this is more functional: <?php echo getenv("username"); ?>

Answer (score 0):

here it is...i've got it!

```
C:\\Users\\'.getenv("username").'\\AppData\\Roaming\\xXXx\\xXXx\\xXXx.exe"))
```

Comment: `getenv("usererprofile")` instead of `C:\\Users\\'.getenv("username")` might be helpful too.